# Why override Java.util.TimerTask()?

Tags: java, android

This code part is taken from a github for continuously scanning the wifi network signal strength:
https://github.com/schollz/find3-android-scanner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/internalpositioning/find3/find3app/ScanService.java

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            if (isScanning == false) {
                                doScan();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                0
        );
```

followed by 4 more written exactly the same but with 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000 ms wait instead of the 0 of this in the second last line.

I'm trying to understand what exactly it is doing.
It seems that the only real function of it is to wait for 0 seconds, 10 seconds, 20 seconds...

So what is the point of having it written like that, and having the same code repeated 5 times? Is there not any better way to do this?

Comment: It think you can store the TimerTask object and call it 5 time in schedule();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could probably change the first 4 `TimerTask` to reuse a common class but the 5th one is different because it also stops the service with `stopSelf()` method:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(
       new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (isScanning == false) {
                        doScan();
                    }
                }
                stopSelf(); // stop the service
            }
        },
        40000
);
```

If you examine file history [87827a01019bfb4b18d059f6cfb401b58926590f commit](https://github.com/schollz/find3-android-scanner/commit/87827a01019bfb4b18d059f6cfb401b58926590f#diff-3646def8993fbee8a30007355d7eb8e3) added repeated `TimerTask`s to improve frequency of the scanning. Previously there were only 3 `TimerTask` after this commit there are 5. Looks like quick fix without refactoring the code.